# Incremental loads in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have a table in Teradata which is loaded with new data on daily basis.

I need to import this data to Hive. I'm trying to use Sqoop but how should I do incremental load using Sqoop?

I checked incremental load options available in Sqoop

```
--check-col
```

This options expects only numeric and unique data whereas my Teradata table is not having such column

I'm using date  column inn --spli-by

How can I do incremental imports to Hive in this case?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `--incremental lastmodified` mode then your `--check-column` is a timestamp that does not need to be numeric or unique.

See: [Sqoop incremental imports](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports).

Comment: Hey Thanks...I want to load daily data that is coming into my TD table using sqoop , data is not getting updated..it is just appending a newly data to Hive table , will --incremental lastmodified work in this case?

Comment: Yes, in many cases you can merge incremental loads using `sqoop merge`: see https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_merge_literal.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply..--incremental appen is working for me

Comment: How can i reset value of --last-value in case of corrupt data coming into hive and need to be deleted then reload

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I have another problem if you can suggest something..if --last-value is 23rd then it will load data for 24 .but if I'm running on 23rd morning then 24th morning will it load data of 23rd evening? If not what will be solution?

Answer (score 0):

use one more "--append " command after the check column so that , the new data will not be replaced and you can see it saves in a new file in hdfs without replacing the old file.